# fopen() segfault, file exists

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fopen

I'm having the following problem: fopen() gives Segmentation Fault, although the file exists and is accessible and the path is right. I have all the necessary includes.

```
int base(char* dir){

char* pot;
pot=malloc(sizeof(char)*512);
struct dirent *pointerDir;
DIR *pDir;
int pid;
char* ime;
char stanje;
int ppid;


pDir = opendir (dir);
if (pDir == NULL) {
    printf ("Cannot open directory '%s'\n", dir);
    return 1;
}

int i=0;

while ((pointerDir = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
    char* str=malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    i=i+1;
    int n=atoi(pointerDir->d_name);

    if(n!=0){

        strcpy(pot, dir);
        sprintf(str, "%d", n);
        strcat(pot, str);
        strcat(pot, "/");
        strcat(pot, "stat");
        printf("pot: %s \n", pot);
        //open file
        FILE* dat=fopen(pot, "r");  
        if(dat!= NULL){
            //do something
        }
        else{
            printf("NULL \n");
        }
    }
}
closedir (pDir);


return 0;
}
```

My output is:

`PID: 1 
pot: /proc/1/stat 
Segmentation fault`

Thank you for any ideas...

Comment: You're not initializing the pointer `pot`

Comment: So you're getting a segmentation fault in the section of the code that you have replaced with the comment `//do something`, and you want people unfamiliar with your code to figure out the problem?  I would guess you should write `//do something incorrectly`, and that may be more enlightening.

Comment: Does the file `/proc/1/stat` need a file extension?, eg. `/proc/1/stat.txt`

Comment: Thank you for the answers, i initialized the pointer 'pot'.
Here is the missing part, but i don't think the mistake is here, because that first line is print, that doesn't go through.

`printf("test");
fscanf(dat, "%d %s %c %d", &pid, &ime, &stanje, &ppid);
fclose(dat);
printf("%s %c %d \n", ime, stanje, ppid);`

Answer (score 1):

From your latest comment and code, the pointer `ime` does not have any memory allocated. That is causing the segfault when fscanf tries to write to it.

use

`fscanf(dat, "%d %s %c %d", &pid, ime, &stanje, &ppid);` as ime is a pointer itself.